# c# Extract sentences using Regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

First of all sorry if this question has been asked several times but I can't figure out how to solve it even after checking the existing answers.
I'm new with Regexp and what I'm trying to do is to extract the sentence(s) between the double quotes after the string "Translate" knowing that the latter string may appear several unknown times and the sentence between the doubles quotes can contain digits and special characters.

For example, with the expression below:

```
'RadMessageBox.Show(Translate("Problem with arguments"), Translate("Error!"), Translate("Bad digital format, it must be of the form 112.3456E12."), MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error);'
```

I would have:

```
'Problem with arguments      Error!      Bad digital format, it must be of the form 112.3456E12.'
```

Comment: `Translate` is not a string. It's a method you're calling

Comment: The text you posted looks like code. Are you looking for a regex to extract the strings between the quotes from your source code files? Or are you trying to change the behavior of the running program?

Comment: Ofc it has since I'm trying to extract the sentences using Regex...

Comment: Totally Cid, Translate is a method

Comment: Yes gnud, it's a code and I'm looking for a regex to extract the strings between the quotes from my source code

Comment: @othale are you looking to do that from your IDE ? If so, what IDE are you using ? VS Studio ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in fact, i'd rather say that it has nothing to do with C#

Comment: At least one thing cleared out. Still, the question is far from being clear, with text containing `Problem with arguments` and expected output as `Insufficient Number of arguments`

Answer (score 0):

Dot NET [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions): `@"Translate\(""([^""]+)"`, next you should join results.

Answer (score 0):

The following would give you the strings, including the quotation marks: `"[^["]*.]*`.

If you wanna remove them, you can use a simple `string.Split('"')`

You can practice building regex yourself using the following website: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
const string sent = "RadMessageBox.Show(Translate(\"Problem with arguments\"), Translate(\"Error!\"), Translate(\"Bad digital format, it must be of the form 112.3456E12.\"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Error);";
const string pattern = "([\"'])(?:\\1|.)*?\\1";

var results = Regex.Matches(sent, pattern);
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var match in results)
{
    sb.Append(match.ToString().Trim('"') + " ");
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

If I understood the question correctly, that's a working example

Comment: That works fine @crankedrelic thank you !
Can you plz describe how did you compose the pattern ?

Comment: You 're welcome. Have a look here http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/match-quoted-string

Comment: As you 'll see you can edit the pattern by removing ' , to only match double quotes

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but that pattern will substring whatever sentences or characters between doubles quotes.

However if I have something like this (see below), it's not going to get me only sentences given to my Translate method: 

`msgerror += Translate("
The symbol used below the named symbol") + " \"" + symbol.name + "\"" + Translate(", row") + (symbol.row + 1) +
                                         Translate(" column ") + (symbol.column + 1) + Translate(", is not correct.") + "\n";`

Can you tell me what pattern should I use in that case plz ?